# Adding two sub column within one pivot column

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, pivot

[image: This is my output for current code]
I have mentioned below code which  gives me pivot table on the basis of task assigned.I want to split pivot header with sub column as start date ad end date. how do i add subcolumn within pivot column

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_pivottask_datewise1
AS
SELECT ProjectName
    ,ProjectNos
    ,isnull([Questionnaire Submission for sripting], '') AS Questionnaire_Submission_for_sripting
    ,isnull([Programing of questionnaire and/or ConJoint Design/Email Send   out], '') AS Programing_of_questionnaire_and_or_ConJoint_Design_Email_Send_out
    ,isnull([Quality Check (Desktop and Mobile)], '') AS Quality_Check_Desktop_and_Mobile
    ,isnull([Questionaire link sent to client for review], '') AS Questionaire_link_sent_to_client_for_review
    ,isnull([Hard Launch], '') AS Hard_Launch
    ,isnull([Data Collection], '') AS Data_Collection
    ,isnull([Quality Check (Sampling)], '') AS Quality_Check_Sampling
    ,isnull([Status of sampling process sent to client], '') AS Status_of_sampling_process_sent_to_client
    ,isnull([Data Exported & Cleansed], '') AS Data_Exported_Cleansed
    ,isnull([Coding of Open Answers], '') AS Coding_of_Open_Answers
    ,isnull([Table Report], '') AS Table_Report
    ,isnull([PPT Report], '') AS PPT_Report
    ,isnull([Data Analysis], '') AS Data_Analysis
    ,isnull([Raw Data Delivery to CDT], '') AS Raw_Data_Delivery_to_CDT
    ,isnull([Quality Check ( Table Report/Raw Data)], '') AS Quality_Check_Table_Report_Raw_Data
    ,isnull([Power Point Quality Check ], '') AS Power_Point_Quality_Check
    ,isnull([Final Presentation Delivery to CDT], '') AS Final_Presentation_Delivery_to_CDT
    ,isnull([Extra Analysis (after presentation)], '') AS Extra_Analysis_after_presentation
    ,isnull([N-visualize report], '') AS Nvisualize_report
    ,isnull([Excel Delivery], '') AS Excel_Delivery
FROM (
    SELECT ProjectName
        ,ProjectNos
        ,convert(VARCHAR(10), Startdate, 103) AS startdate
        ,convert(VARCHAR(10), enddate, 103) AS enddate
        ,[Task_assigned]
    FROM tbl_ProjectDetails
    WHERE flag = '0'
    ) AS t
PIVOT(max(startdate) FOR [Task_assigned] IN (
            [Questionnaire Submission for sripting]
            ,[Programing of questionnaire and/or ConJoint Design/Email Send out]
            ,[Quality Check (Desktop and Mobile)]
            ,[Questionaire link sent to client for review]
            ,[Hard Launch]
            ,[Data Collection]
            ,[Quality Check (Sampling)]
            ,[Status of sampling process sent to client]
            ,[Data Exported & Cleansed ]
            ,[Coding of Open Answers]
            ,[Table Report]
            ,[PPT Report]
            ,[Data Analysis]
            ,[Raw Data Delivery to CDT]
            ,[Quality Check ( Table Report/Raw Data)]
            ,[Power Point Quality Check ]
            ,[Final Presentation Delivery to CDT]
            ,[Extra Analysis (after presentation)]
            ,[N-visualize report]
            ,[Excel Delivery]
            )) AS pivottable
```

[image: This is my expected output]

Comment: Do you mean headers like **CROSSTAB** reports?

Comment: I have already done crosstab.... but now what i need is under this column in pivot table i need subcolumns... meaning each task will have two columns under them for start date and end date. i could get task with one date each how do i show two more columns under them

Comment: You cannot show columns under a column in SQL SERVER. For that you need to use SSRS or some other reporting services. One way you can do is show columns like Taks1StartDate,Task1EndDate,Taks2StartDate,Task2EndDate etc etc. Is that enough? @user2583182

Comment: @SarathAvanavu:  i dont mind showing Taks1StartDate,Task1EndDate,Taks2StartDate,Task2EndDate etc etc  but how do i show this with pivot

Comment: Can show that. Before that I need to clarify. Do u need a static pivot or dynamic pivot? @user2583182

Comment: @SarathAvanavu: i have edited my question where i have shown the printscreen of current current page and expected output in excel.  also what i am doing is dynamic pivot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69120/discussion-between-sarath-avanavu-and-user2583182).